# Converting only time in python

Tags: python, csv, time

I'm working with lines of text in a csv file similar to this:

```
 2012-03-16     13:47:31.915    -0400       image
```

I want to be able to run a for loop through the csv file, and subtract just the time in between each line of code. Currently, I can only do it through the date and time, but it's causing some confusion. This what I have now.

```
    newLogFile = csv.reader(open('newLogFile.csv', 'r+'), delimiter="\t")
    row_count = sum(1 for row in csv.reader( open('newLogFile.csv') ) )
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'


    for row in newLogFile:
      time = (row[0] + " " + row[1])


      ts1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, fmt)

      row_count+=1
      if row_count == 33:
         current = ts1
         current = ts1 - current

      print ("%s - %s" %(ts1,current))
      current = ts1 - current
      print current
```

The output looks something like this:

```
    2012-03-16 13:52:09.462000 - 0:01:44.866000
    2012-03-16 13:50:24.596000
```

I tried looking through the datetime and time modules but I couldn't find anything that would have worked. I know there is something wrong in the subtraction as well, but I want to get the conversion correct first.

Thanks for the help

**UPDATE:**

I figured out my problem...

```
newLogFile = csv.reader(open('newLogFile.csv', 'r+'), delimiter="\t")

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
row_count = 0

for row in newLogFile:
    time = (row[0] + " " + row[1])
    timestamp = strptime(time, fmt)
    current_value = mktime(timestamp)

    row_count+=1
    if row_count == 1:
        previous_value = current_value

    print ("%s - %s" %(current_value, previous_value))
    total_value = current_value - previous_value
    print total_value

    previous_value = current_value
```

I decided to set the time to seconds to find out a more exact and reliable value. I also fixed my subtraction as well, by changing the row_count and reseting the previous_value to the current_value before ending the for loop

Comment: Are you sure that's the output? `current=ts1;current = ts1 - current` can't possible set `current` to anything other than `timedelta(0)`, surely.

Comment: I just re-ran it and this is what I got. 2012-03-16 13:52:24.563000 - 2012-03-16 13:50:33.944000
0:01:50.619000.

Comment: If you say so. I can't see any way the code you posted could possibly produce that output, but good luck.

Comment: I figured out my problem. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, see the update under the original question.

```
newLogFile = csv.reader(open('newLogFile.csv', 'r+'), delimiter="\t")

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
row_count = 0

for row in newLogFile:
    time = (row[0] + " " + row[1])
    timestamp = strptime(time, fmt)
    current_value = mktime(timestamp)

    row_count+=1
    if row_count == 1:
        previous_value = current_value

    print ("%s - %s" %(current_value, previous_value))
    total_value = current_value - previous_value
    print total_value

    previous_value = current_value
```